# In Delphi, when coding a custom package, I get the error "Package not found" unless "Link with runtime libraries" is true

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create my own package in Delphi / RAD Studio XE8.

After creating the bpl & dcp and placing them in the correct folder (C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\Bpl and \Dcp), adding them via "Install packages", I'm trying add my unit to the 'uses' section.

However, the Delphi IDE cannot find my unit "Unit ... not found", UNLESS I activate "Link with runtime libraries" to true.

But I would like to ship my package with my EXE, so this is not an option for production.

What to do?

Comment: You just need to make sure that the source code for the used units is visible to the compiler. Either add the units to the project, or include their locations in the project search path.

Comment: does this mean that I need to distribute the source code if I share this library with a 3rd party developer? If yes, why?

Comment: Hang on, I've misread your question. You say that you want to ship your package with your executable. In which case surely you want to link with runtime packages? If you don't link with runtime packages then what's the point of shipping your package. I'd assumed that you wanted not to ship the package which is why you'd disabled linking with runtime packages. So, I'm confused. I think some more clarity is needed.

Comment: I'm new to Delphi so I may not get basic concepts right, please apologise. I'm trying to ship a piece of code that a 3rd party developer can use in their EXE, without having to have access to the source code. In the Java world, I would do this by shipping a .jar.

Comment: What compiler is the other developer using? If you want to use packages then they have to be using the exact same compiler as you. Not enough to use Delphi, has to be the same version of Delphi. If that is the case you ship BPL, DCP and documentation. Without documentation the other developer has no chance of using your package. The other developer has to link to runtime packages. Anyway, none of that is source, so I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I'm wondering what the Delphi concept of "shipping a piece of code for 3rd party developers to integrate into their EXE without sharing the source code" is. I thought that is packages, but it turns out that I'm mistaken.

Comment: No, it really is packages. You ship the BPL, DCP and documentation, and the other developers link to it using runtime packages. You have to ship one version for every different Delphi compiler version that you wish to support.